# Solving Schrödinger equation with potentials of all the fundamental forces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

What if I were to substitute all the potential energy terms in the Schrödinger equation, I.e., Nuclear(strong) PE, nuclear(weak) PE, electrostatic PE, electroweak PE and Gravitational PE.
(Also with Chemical PE, Elastic PE).How do I go about solving and analysing such a system?
Would the equation look like this:

$$∇²\psi+\frac{2m}{(h/2\pi)^2}\left(E- \dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\alpha_s(r) \hbar c}{r} + kr - \frac{g^2}{4 \pi c^2} \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}+mgz +\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}-K\frac{1}{r}e^{-mr}\right)\psi=0$$

Where $$ \dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\alpha_s(r) \hbar c}{r} + kr$$ is the potential for strong force,$$- \frac{g^2}{4 \pi c^2} \frac{e^{-mr}}{r}$$ is the Yukawa potential and $$-K\frac{1}{r}e^{-mr}$$ is the weak field potential.( The other two are the gravitational and Coulombic potentials).

Comment: I didn't downvote @naveen; but I guess it is due to that your query _ how can I solve this?_ is very much sounding like a homework query. [tag:homework] doesn't go here with the literal meaning; click on it to know more about it and the policy here) .Please note that Phys.SE is not a homework helping site.

Comment: @MAFIA36790 But this is not a homework question. I am aware of the homework policy, all I wanted was help.

Comment: (I wasn't the one who downvoted this) I would be very surprised if treating the stong and weak forces in a non-relativistic setting like this were to give any meaningfull results. In particular, what quantum system are you trying to discribe? A single particle influenced by all fundamental forces? Also I'm somewhat puzzled by your use of the variables $z$ and $r$. In 3 spacial dimensions it should be $$\Delta \psi +\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(E-V)\psi=0$$
(your Coulomb potential is wrong, independant of position)

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Thanks a lot for pointing that out, I have edited it. And yes, I'm trying to model a particle influenced by all the forces although it's seems very unrealistic.

Comment: When someone downvotes it's because they think the post is not a good question. For example, it could be unclear or it could be asking too many different things at once. Your objection "If you know so much mr.downvoter..." is sort of nonsense because downvotes do not have anything to do with whether or not the downvoter knows the answer. I strongly recommend you to look around the site and get an idea of what makes a good question before using such negative and unhelpful tone. Enjoy the site.

Comment: @DanielSank Sure,thanks a lot! I was just kind of upset that I'm being judged for asking a question that I really thought about. As for that initial comment I made, it's just sarcasm, nothing harmful.

Comment: First of all, nobody is judging *you*, they're judging the question. Keep that in your mind always. If you do, you'll get better at asking questions and better at physics. If you don't, you'll get emotionally upset at opportunities where you could instead learn something. Second, your comment *is* harmful. It immediately made me not want to help you and it makes our site look antagonistic to new users. I encourage you to remove that comment. If you don't, I might flag it as inappropriate.

Comment: @DanielSank Sure I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: No one even bothers to write a potential for the weak interaction. It's simple not a meaningful way to try to understand what is going on, and if you did it would be zero at all meaningful distances (at modest energy the range might be as 'large' at $10^{-20}\,\mathrm{m}$.

Comment: @dmckee      
Yeah I'm aware it's unrealistic. Just trying to model a particle influenced by all the forces and study the results and see the deviation from the results obtained from QED.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that the right adjective isn't "unrealistic" it's somewhere between "totally doolally" and "completely meaningless".

Comment: @dmckee Yeah Sure. Being in the adjective space you described,I was just trying this to see how crazy an answer I get.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I don't think there exists an exact solution for this (very complicated) differential equation.

Second there's no real physical interpretation/use for this equation for the following reasons:

- All of these potentials are only approximations for these interactions (you need the relativistic field theories, e.g. QED or QCD to describe them correctly)
- This equation describes a particle in one dimension which is affected by all fundamental forces at the same time, and the strength of all forces only depends on the same variable $r$. It is not very difficult to see that this is a very unrealistic description of nature.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware it's unrealistic. Just trying to model a particle influenced by all the forces and study the results and see the deviation from the results obtained from QED.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji
You will not get any deviations from QED because you cannot even get the predictions of QED in this way. QED is a relativistic quantum field theory where a dirac spin 1/2 field couples to a spin 1 gauge field. The standard framework is aimed at computing cross sections for scattering experiments. What you are doing is not a quantum field theory. A theory with "fixed particle number" is inconsistent with [quantum theory & special relativity] and you only have one particle.